# OpenURL in private browsing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to use openURL to start Mobile Safari in private mode. I can't find any information on this and whether it should be done using the annotation or the URL scheme

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, currently there is no way to do that. You can't even turn on private browsing programmatically.